# Что Вы можете сказать о книге "Самый полный курс русского языка", написанной Адамчиков?

Tags: другое

Я ее читаю сейчас. Мне просто интересно, читал ли ее кто-нибудь из тех, кто тут обитает. ;) Эта книга действительно похожа на полный курс, поэтому я подумал, что если Вы не читали ее, то что читали Вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Полный курс русского языка" не читают, а изучают - потихоньку, с 1 класса по 11,всё это есть в школьных учебниках,после школы можно пользоваться ЛЮБЫМ справочником по необходимости, если в чём-то сомневаешься, а  **читают** художественную литературу.

Comment: Это вообще-то книга, поэтому можно употребить глагол читать.

Comment: Обычно читают главу или параграф из учебника, но не сами учебники. Цель - изучить конкретный материал, или повторить его, или найти нужную информацию. С учебниками работают, а не читают их. Соответственно, сочетание "читаю учебник" представляется не очень корректным, напрягает слух.

Answer (score 3):

> > > Плюнь тому в глаза, кто скажет, что можно обнять необъятное!

Козьма Петрович.
(+)
В мои годы считалось, что самые обширные, исчерпывающие и фундаментальные труды должны иметь название типа "Краткое введение в избранные главы анализа". Идея создания ОТВ (Общей Теории Всего) еще не была тогда так популярна.

Answer (score 1):

Самый полный курс русского языка / Авт.
Н. В. Адамчик. — Минск: Харвест, 2008. — 848 с.

"Пособие написано в соогветствии с программой по русскому языку, действующей в современной школе. Теоретический материал изложен полно, логично и доступно, Пособие ориентировано на тех, кто хочет углубленно изучать русский язык. Оно содержит развернутый (по сравнению со школьными учебниками) теоретический матери&т, охватывающий все разделы современного языка. Основное назначение книги — помочь в осознании вопросов теории, развить способность самостоятельно анализировать различные явления русского языка, а также разобраться в сложных вопросах при подготовке к тестированию. Для школьников, абитуриентов, учителей русского языка, студентов, а также всех, кто интересуется русским языком и желает повысить свою грамотность и культуру речи".

У нас очень много учебников по русскому языку, их количество все увеличивается, но все они похожи, как близнецы. Вы хотите написать учебник? Тогда, чтобы его покупали и читали, надо придумать красивое название, например: "Самый полный учебник". Чтобы он действительно таким казался, можно украсить его небольшим количеством дополнительных сведений по истории орфографии, или более подробной характеристикой фонемного состава языка, или еще чем-нибудь в этом роде. Но на этом оригинальная часть заканчивается, все остальное содержание какая-нибудь антиплагиатная система обязана признать неуникальным.

Не стоит говорить, что это плохой учебник, - это просто нормальный учебник, из которого можно почерпнуть полезные сведения, но это можно сделать и с помощью других пособий. По крайней мере, пролистав несколько тем, никакого особого авторства и "никаких открытий чудных" я там не обнаружила.

Comment: А стоит ли тогда выпускать новые учебники в таком количестве, если всё, что там есть, уже написано в других?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос так и не прозвучал, к сожалению. Никто не захотел раскрыть тайну своих знаний. Промолчу и я. Позволю себе лишь некоторое суждение по поводу вышесказанного: чтобы изучить книгу, её надо прочесть, возможно, не один раз. Если вы хотите изучить русский язык для оценок в школе, возможно, вам поможет труд Адамчикова. Если же для себя - врядли.

Comment: Нет, оценки мне не нужны.